# 4G Mi-Fi hotspot : unlocking a hotspot will increase speeds?

Tags: wireless-router, hotspot, mobile-broadband, wireless-hotspot, mifi

**Brief background of question:**

I have Alcatel MW40-0B46 Mifi 4G hotspot device [image: Alcatel MW40-0B46 Mifi 4G hotspot device].
Initially it was locked for 'Airtel' carrier.

It was getting halted very often (even after trying obvious things such as changing place to find better network, restarting the device, checking APN, changing the connection type between 'Auto' and '4G only' etc.).

Then I got it unlocked by using nck (network code key), put in another SIM of 'Idea' carrier and it's working fine.

Just for curiosity, I again put back 'Airtel' SIM.
To my surprise, now it is working without halting.

**My question** is, whether unlocking a Mi-Fi device can cause performance increase? Is it possible?

Comment: Unlocking shouldn't have to do with anything else but the ability to use other services. It's probably a coincidence.

Comment: You also need to consider the strength of the signal in both carriers. It can be just a coincidence as far I know. Generally, unlocking the hotspot won't increase speed (probably with a custom firmware it's possible).